# FreeNAS unable to resolve hostnames, ping of any external IP returns host's ip instead

Tags: ping, truenas, jail

The internal IP address of my router changed, and ever since TrueNAS has been misbehaving. None of the jails can resolve a hostname anymore. In troubleshooting this, I discovered that the client cannot ping any external IP address without the response being from the host.

*For info:*

- In this example, the client jail's IP is 10.153.2.250
- The host's (FreeNAS) IP is 10.153.2.9
- The new gateway is 10.0.55.1 (old was 10.55.0.1), and this has been updated in both the host's network configuration and the jails'.
- When the gateway IP changed, FreeNAS got into a boot loop on the next startup ... apparently to a DNS resolution failure. As I recall (it was 3am and my mind was foggy), updating the nameserver and route finally fixed it.
- An SMB share on the host stopped working at the same time (and still hasn't come back)

Cannot ping domain names:

```
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.553/15.790/16.027/0.237 ms
root@jail:~ # ping google.com
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Host name lookup failure
```

If manually I tell the jail client to look up a domain, I get an IP address back:

```
root@jail:~ # host google.com
google.com has address 172.217.15.110
google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 8 smtp.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

HOWEVER, for any IP address that I ping from within the jail client, the response is from the IP of the jail's host (FreeNAS). Pinging the same IPs from the host gets a normal response.

```
root@jail:~ # ping 172.217.15.110
PING 172.217.15.110 (172.217.15.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.153.2.9: icmp_seq=0 ttl=116 time=30.454 ms
64 bytes from 10.153.2.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=30.235 ms
64 bytes from 10.153.2.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=30.534 ms
^C
--- 172.217.15.110 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 30.235/30.408/30.534/0.126 ms
```

Another example (note the host's IP, 10.153.2.9, in the response):

```
root@jail:~ # ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.153.2.9: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=16.027 ms
64 bytes from 10.153.2.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=15.553 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

But, if I ping another internal IP (other than that of the router), I get the expected response:

```
root@jail:~ # ping 10.153.2.205
PING 10.153.2.205 (10.153.2.205): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.153.2.205: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.295 ms
64 bytes from 10.153.2.205: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.237 ms
64 bytes from 10.153.2.205: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.193 ms
^C
--- 10.153.2.205 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.193/0.242/0.295/0.042 ms
root@jail:~
```

Here is the result of `netstat -rn` from within the host. I'm not too familiar with this output, but nothing sticks out to me as amiss (and it closely resembles the host's version):

```
root@jail:~ # netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            10.0.55.1          UGS     epair0b
10.0.0.0/8         link#3             U       epair0b
10.153.2.250       link#3             UHS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#1             UH          lo0

Internet6:
Destination                       Gateway                       Flags     NetifExpire
::/96                             ::1                           UGRS        lo0
::1                               link#1                        UH          lo0
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96                 ::1                           UGRS        lo0
fe80::/10                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#1                        U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0                       link#1                        UHS         lo0
ff02::/16                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0
```

Here are the contents of the client's `resolv.conf` (identical to the host's `resolv.conf`, and predictably matches the settings in the FreeNAS network configuration):

```
root@jail:~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
search local
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.55.1
root@jail:~
```

I checked the arp cache and the MAC addresses are correct.

SO....why would the jail be getting the host's IP back in a ping response?

Comment: Look's like you have a network loop. -> `default 10.0.55.1 UGS epair0b` and `10.0.0.0/8 link#3 U epair0b` are routing into the same network (The same network where your router-gateway is.).

Comment: @paladin I don't think that's an issue. I made a fresh TrueNAS install with a fresh jail, and its routing rules looked about the same.